# Generate "characters" based on a probability

Tags: c++, random, probability

I need a little help with my tetris game
that I am coding in C++ , here is my problem:

The list of tetris blocks are 7 types:
{'I', 'J', 'L', 'S', 'Z', 'O', 'T'}

and i need to pick ONE of the above character such that
S and Z are selected with probability 1/12 each, and the other blocks are selected with
probability 1/6 each.

What is my best way to generate the blocks according to these probabilities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weighted random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761626/weighted-random-numbers)

Comment: If you got a useful answer, accept it (see [ask])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array like so:

```
const char* block_distribution = {'I', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'L', 'L', 'S', 
                                  'Z', 'O', 'O', 'T', 'T'};
```

Then pick one element from that array using a uniform distribution.

Comment: Thankyou, I have made the array, now I just have to generate a random numbber from [0,11] , do you know exactly how I can do that? I am not familiar with random number generation in c++

Comment: @Shehryar This should be an exercise left for the reader. This is easy enough to look up in pretty much every reference manual.

Comment: @ShehryarFarooq: Make sure your answer isn't `rand() % 12`, which doesn't do what you asked!

Answer (score 7):

Declare and define a twelve-item array with a single occurrence of S and Z; two occurrences each of the rest; and pick a random element from that.

Answer (score 1):

put those characters in a character array and generate random values from 0 to 6 with `srand()`
than you can get a random

> char myArray[] = {'I', 'J', 'L', 'S', 'Z', 'O', 'T'};

and then get values with

> myArray[ (rand()%5)+1 ]

Comment: Hi johnny, i use this method if I want them to be generated with EQUAL probability correct?

Comment: yes, initial srand() with the time in the main function to prevent always the same "random" value

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of is to use numeric ranges and pseudo-random numbers.

So, first assign ranges to each letter:

I: 0 to 1
J: 1 to 2
L: 2 to 3
S: 3 to 3.5
Z: 3.5 to 4
O: 4 to 5
T: 5 to 6

then generate pseudo-random numbers within the range 0 to 6. Whichever part of the range that the number falls within, that's the letter you choose.

Unfortunately I do not know C++ so I cannot provide you with code, but I don't think it should be too difficult to implement.