# how to generate numbers to determine weighted race winners

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, random

I need to find a way of picking winners, for like a race. Each racer has a weight of the chances of winning..

for instance

```
A - 25% chance to win
B - 10% chance to win
C - 25% chance to win
D - 10% chance
E - 10% chance
F - 20% chance
```

1) I need to pick the winner randomly but need to take the weighting in consideration.

2) I also need to pick the second most likely winner and the third...

I could pick the first by generating a random winner between 1-100 and basically splitting 100 among the racers depending on there chances like:

```
A = 1-25
B = 26 -35
C = 36-60.
etc
etc
```

Not sure how the stability of the above, but seemed okay.

Any more ideas?

Comment: Seems like you already have the answer to your question.  Bear in mind that most random numbers will be zero-based.

Comment: Someone has already solved this problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761626/weighted-random-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class RaceWinners{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] percentages = {25,10,25,10,10,20};
        System.out.print(pickWinner(percentages));
    }

    //Returns the index of the winner(A = 0, B = 1, ...)
    private static int pickWinner(int[] percentages) {
        int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        int countdown = randomNumber;
        for(int i = 0; i < percentages.length; i++) {
            countdown -= percentages[i];
            if(countdown < 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
   }

}
```

Comment: I think this algorithm is a bit partial in favor of the Racer who are in the beginning in array `percentages`. For eg, 3rd and 1st element should have equal probability of being picked randomly, but this algorithm will favor 3rd member. However, if we also randomize value of `i` this problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the first rank you can do as you have described. But for the second, third,... places are little bit different (if A is first, then B has probability to be second p(B|A) := "the second is B given that the first is A", then B has not 10% to be second but a different value to be second and so on for the others members). Take a look at the condition probability (wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability )

this is a "pseudocode" that do the job

```
Ranking:
begin probability
a = 20%
b = 10%
...

calculate first
recalculate probability given that first is X (e.g. if first is A p(B|A), p(C|A),...)
calculate second (with the new probability, e.g. b = p(B|A), c = p(C|A),..)
recalculate probability given that first is X and second is Y
calculate third
etc..
```

NOTE: java random (Math.random) generates value between 0 and 0.999999... (e.g. [0, 1[ 0 is included but 1 not)

Comment: Conditional probability will come in picture if it is confirmed that A won (may be during second run of the program), else probability calculated in first go should be ok.

Comment: @Aditya sure, the first go is ok. But for the others (to determine second, third,...etc if first is A or B or C...) you must use the conditional probability.

Comment: @damoiser - I agree, what i ended up doing was once the winner was determined. I recalculated each racers probability and than proceeded to find next racer to complete.