# actionscript 3, gotoandstop random frame out of next 3

Tags: flash, actionscript, random, frame

so on my flash, I have parts where you have option which way to choose, and that road you choose should have randomization in them, and I am trying to build it so that when user chooses one road, he is thrown into one of the 3 labeled frames randomly, and I have even considered of adding some of the randomization parts a road that has most least chance to happen.

```
    stop();

road1a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, firstroadA);

function firstroadA(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(this.currentFrame == 9){
        var randomNumber:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
        if (randomNumer == 0){
            gotoAndStop(10);
        }
        if (randomNumber == 1){
            gotoAndStop(11);
        }
        if (randomNumber == 2){
            gotoAndStop(12);
        }
    }
    else{
        nextFrame();
    }

}
```

on this test, I have tried to do it so that the user´s choice happens in 9th frame, and when he chooses to click firstroadA he goes to some of the random frames, 10, 11 or 12... so, I hope I have been clear enough; **my question is in a nutshell, how do I randomize the gotoAndStop frames, and how do I add some rare frames that has lesser chance to be chosen to gotoAndStop.... thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can as you want using weighted random numbers. Check out this code, it does as you want:

```
stop();

gotoAndStop(9);

road1a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, firstroadA);

function firstroadA(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(this.currentFrame == 9)
    {
        // These are the weight chance for each "road"
        // I used 30%, 50%, and 10% arbitrarily
        var choiceWeights:Array = [30, 50, 10];

        // frame choices
        var roadFrames = [10, 11, 12];

        // get a weighted random
        var r:int = makeChoiceWithWeight(choiceWeights);

        //go to the selected frame
        gotoAndStop(roadFrames[r]);
    }
    else
    {
        nextFrame();
    }
}

function makeChoiceWithWeight(choiceWeights:Array):int
{
    var sumOfWeights:int = 0;
    var numWeights:int = choiceWeights.length;

    // add all weights
    for(var i:Number = 0; i < numWeights; i++) sumOfWeights += choiceWeights[i];

    // pick a random number greater than zero and less than the total of weights
    var rnd:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*sumOfWeights);

    //keep reducing the random number until less than a choices weight
    for(var ii:Number = 0; ii < numWeights; ii++)
    {
        if(rnd < choiceWeights[ii]) return ii;

        rnd -= choiceWeights[ii];
    }

    // should never reach this point
    return 0;
}
```

For a deeper look into weighted random number check this SO answer:
[Weighted random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761626/weighted-random-numbers)