# Randomly pick tables basis on there percentage by generating Random Number

Tags: java, random

I am working on a project in which I have two tables in a different database with different schemas. So that means I have two different connection parameters for those two tables to connect using JDBC-

Let's suppose below is the config.property file- in which `table1.percentage` means `80%` of time `table1` will be picked and `20%` of time `table2` will be picked basis on the random number.

```
TABLES: table1 table2

#For Table1
table1.percentage: 80    

#For Table2
table2.percentage: 20
```

Below method will read the above `config.property` file and make a `ReadTableConnectionInfo` object for each tables.

```
private static HashMap<String, ReadTableConnectionInfo> tableList = new HashMap<String, ReadTableConnectionInfo>();

private static void readPropertyFile() throws IOException {

    prop.load(Read.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    tableNames = Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("TABLES").split(" "));

    for (String arg : tableNames) {

        ReadTableConnectionInfo ci = new ReadTableConnectionInfo();

        double percentage = Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty(arg + ".percentage"));

        ci.setPercentage(percentage);

    tableList.put(arg, ci);
    }
}
```

Below is the `ReadTableConnectionInfo` class that will hold all the `table connection info` for a particular table.

```
public class ReadTableConnectionInfo {

    public String percentage;

    public double getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(double percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }
}
```

Now in my run method each thread has to generate random number and then decide which table I need to use depending on the percentage for each tables.

```
private static Random random = new SecureRandom();


@Override
public run() {
  ...


  while ( < 60 minutes) {
    double randomNumber = random.nextDouble() * 100.0;
    ReadTableConnectionInfo tableInfo = selectRandomConnection(randomNumber);

    // do query...
  }
}


//Any problem with the below method?
private ReadTableConnectionInfo selectRandomConnection(double randomNumber) {
  double limit = 0;
  for (ReadTableConnectionInfo ci : tableLists.values()) {
    limit += ci.getPercentage();
    if (randomNumber < limit) {
      return ci;
    }
      }
    throw new IllegalStateException();
   }
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Is there any problem in my `selectRandomConnection` method? Because each thread is working for 60 minutes and in that 60 minutes every time it is only picking `table1`.

**What I am looking for is `80%` of time it should pick `table1` and `20%` of time it should pick `table2`.**

Comment: The fact that it is selecting tables is irrelevant. What you want to do is a select a random element from a set of elements, but the probability of any element getting selected is not 1/size-of-set but some other number. Now, please explain why you think `selectRandomConnection` should do this, perhaps using a dry-run

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761626/weighted-random-numbers and other questions on the sidebar there, search for weighted/biased random number generator.

Comment: Have you debugged? Have you verified the randomNumbers are what you expect?

Comment: My mistake, I messed up somehow in my actual code. I figured that out. Thanks guys for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want A to be selected 80% of the time, and B to be selected 20% of the time, on average, just pick a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 100 (exclusive). If the number is < 80, choose A, else choose B.

As simple as that.