# Creating advanced loot systems based on a "luck" value

Tags: random, lua

I am working on a little game and I want to spice up the loot drops with a luck value every player has. For this example, let's say the rarities are r1, r2, r3, ...rn. Luck is also initialized with each character as 0.001 and luck will be used in the code as (log10(luck) + 4) which means that for every power of 10 that luck increases, the value of luck that is used in the code increases by 1. 0.001 gives 1, 0.01 gives 2, etc.

Now this is where I am stalled, when the luck value increases by a "tier" the most common rarity should become r2 if it increases from a luck value of 1 to 2. From 3 to 4 the most common value becomes r3, and both r1 and r2 move down in probability of being selected.

Any advice on how to implement this, Thanks!

Also, I have been looking for a while and have found many random generators that answer the problem of getting weighted loot to work, but not implementing this system of luck.

So far, someone has pointed in the direction of modular division but I cant think of a way to implement it so that as one side of rarities increases while the other decreases.

On the topic of "sides" I have also thought about using a bell curve and cut it into symmetrical chunks using integrals and some equation that calculates how far apart to make the bounds of the integrals. Then each chunk of the bell curve would be assigned a rarity and as the luck value increases from one level to the next, each rarity slides left one chunk leaving the next rarity as the most common and decreasing the rarities before it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weighted random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761626/weighted-random-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

> I have also thought about using a bell curve and cut it into symmetrical chunks

Yes, the idea is correct.
Just round the floating point value on the bell curve to the nearest integer rarity.
The random generator formula is from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)

```
local function random_norm()
   return (-2 * math.log(math.random()))^.5 * math.cos(2 * math.pi * math.random())
end

-- luck  = 0.001 makes "r1" the most probable, luck = 0.01 makes "r2", etc.
local luck = 8.4

-- the more bell_shape_width_factor the bigger the probability to get other rarities
local bell_shape_width_factor = 0.4   -- number from 0 to inf

local central_rarity = 4 + math.log(luck)/math.log(10)
print("central_rarity = "..central_rarity)

for j = 1, 20 do
   local rarity
   repeat
      rarity = math.max(1, math.floor(central_rarity + random_norm() * bell_shape_width_factor + 0.5))
   until 1/rarity ~= 0  -- skip inf values
   print("r"..rarity)
end
```

Output:

```
central_rarity = 4.9242792860619
r6
r5
r5
r5
r4
r5
r5
r5
r5
r6
r5
r5
r5
r5
r5
r5
r5
r5
r4
r5
```